# Find the number of factors in the expression $12^5\cdot 13^{15}\cdot 5^{10}$

Tags: combinations, factoring, prime-factorization

After doing prime factorisation of 12:

There are ten 2s, five 3s, fifteen 13s and ten 5s in this number

A distinct factor of the number is created by taking 0 to 10 2s, 0 to 5 3s, 0 to 15 13s and 0 to 10 5s, and multiplying the choosen numbers together.

So there's 11 ways of picking 2s, 6 ways of picking 3s, 16 ways of picking 13s and 11 ways of picking 5s.

So number of factors = 11*6*16*11=11616

However, this answer is wrong as it is none of the options. What am I doing wrong here?
[image: question image]

Comment: What you done looks good to me. It's possible the source of the problem made a mistake. What are the options given there? (It's sometimes possible to deduce an error from properties of the purported answer.)

Comment: I get the same answer you got.  Can you print the question exactly as it appears, along with the proposed options?  Perhaps they want you to exclude $1$ and the number itself.

Comment: Are you sure you read the problem correctly? Perhaps $12^5$ should be $2^5$ since the other two factors are powers of primes.

Comment: @BarryCipra The given options are 14256, 4536, 4536, 6535, 4356

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah, it's clearly $12^5$. And that shouldn't be any problem as it can be quickly converted to primes.

Comment: @lulu I'll upload a pic. Also, none of the options are anywhere close to 11616. Maybe the options are wrong.

Comment: @RyderRude, does the number $4536$ really appear as an option twice?

Comment: @BarryCipra I accidentally typed it twice lol

Comment: No guess.  For what it's worth, the possible solutions factor as $2^4\times 3^4\times 11, 2^3\times 3^4\times 7, 2^2\times 3^2\times 11^2$ and $5\times 1307$.  Hard to imagine that the $1307$ is possible, but who knows?  Maybe the factorings will suggest something to somebody.

Comment: Well $14256 = 81 \times 16 \times 11$ so that would be the right answer if the $12^5$ factor in the problem was wrong in the right way ...

Comment: @EthanBolker You mean the question is printed wrong?

Comment: @RyderRude The question _may_ be printed wrong. Or the answers may have accidentally excluded the correct one. The gist of all the comments here is that you are right and we are all wondering what's wrong somewhere, so trying to reverse engineer to find the error.

Comment: If the question were asking about $12^5\cdot13^5\cdot5^{10}$ (instead of $13^{15}$), which becomes $2^{10}\cdot3^5\cdot13^5\cdot5^{10}$, the answer would be $11\cdot6\cdot6\cdot11=4356$.

Comment: @BarryCipra  I think you found the typo. Now I can go think about something else.

Comment: @BarryCipra  I think you got it.  Phew.

Comment: @EthanBolker (and lulu), it would be of mild interest to see if there are simple (single-digit?) typos that lead to other options....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning a couple of comments into an answer, your solution to $12^5\cdot13^{15}\cdot5^{10}=2^{10}\cdot3^5\cdot13^{15}\cdot5^{10}$ is entirely correct. It's possible there was a typo in the problem, and that it meant to ask about the number of factors in $12^5\cdot13^5\cdot5^{10}=2^{10}\cdot3^5\cdot13^5\cdot5^{10}$, in which case the answer is $11\cdot6\cdot6\cdot11=4536$, which *is* one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is not on their list.

As you have mentioned ,your  number is $$(3^5)(2^{10})(13^{15})(5^{10})$$

Therefore you have $$(6)(11)(16)(11)=11616$$
divisors.

Comment: The OP knows that and wants to know why that answer matches none of the ones given in the assignment.